# Architecture of Apigility

Tags: api, rest, zend-framework2, laminas-api-tools

I have several Systems under different subdomains working. Every system serves some Restful APIs, which are used by mobile clients. 
Now I looked at apigility for managing those APIs.

But the architecture is not completely clear to me. All of my systems serving APIs are built with Zend Framework 2. 
Will I have to add to every system the apigility component? Or can I set up another subdomain where I will use apigility? Can I there configure the APIs for all systems from one place? Or will I have to configure the apigility for every system seperate?

It would be nice for me, if I can access apigility under api.example.com and then see the different APIs of the systems I have configured. The APIs will be served under the subdomains of the system, for example: 
system1.example.com/api/documents
system2.example.com/api/pictures
etc.

Is this possible with apigility?

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple APIs in one Apigility install.

By default they will be access from yourdomain/apiname/resource or something like this.

One thing that maybe you dont know is that Apigility works with some standards like HAL or the preference of the team developers for not use nested resources (rosource1/resource2/3). If you not work with this maybe you will fight with the framework all day.